# Merge Parent child array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, loops, parent-child

I have PHP array. I am trying to convert into a parent-child array:
I have used a recursive function but not getting my output.

```
Array
(


    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [subscription_name] => Yearly 
            [parent_id] => 0
        )



    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [subscription_name] => Yearly new               
            [parent_id] => 1
        )

    [2 => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [subscription_name] => Yearly new offer 
            [parent_id] => 22
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24
            [subscription_name] => Weekly
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25
            [subscription_name] => Weekly new offer
            [parent_id] => 24
        )

)
```

I expect this result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [subscription_name] => Yearly new offer 
            [childrens] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 22
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 23
                        )   
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24
            [subscription_name] => Weekly new offer 
            [childrens] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 25
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I have tried but not getting my desire Output

My PHP function is

```
function tree(array $elements, $parent_id = 0) {
      echo "<pre>";
        $branch = array();
        $a=array();
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
           if ($element['parent_id'] == $parent_id && $element['subscription_type_id'] !=1 ) {
                $children = $this->tree($elements, $element['id']);
                if ($children) {
                    $element['children'] = $children;
                }
                else {
                    $element['children'] = array();
                }
                $branch[] = $element;
            }

        }
        return $branch;
    }
```

Here is the output I am getting from the above function:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [subscription_name] => Yearly 
        [children] => Array
        (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 22
                        [subscription_name] => Yearly new 
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 23
                                        [subscription_name] => Yearly new offer 
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                        )

                )

    )

)

[1] => Array
(
    [id] => 24
    [subscription_name] => Weekly
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 25
                    [subscription_name] => Weekly new offer 
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: The parent_id of 23 is 22 hence it is appearing under the 22's array. If you want to output as you mentioned above,  you have to change the parent_id of 23 as 1.

Comment: Nor to change to algorithm

Comment: Are you sure that that is the desired output? 
Looking on the initial array for id=0 , it seems to be parent for ids (0, 1, 21) , but I don't see them in the desired output.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54240517/java-create-multiple-tree-like-structure-using-parent-id-from-flat-file/54250743#54250743) can help

Comment: https://3v4l.org/obbWl - check this

Answer (score 1):

Really, i mean REALLY naive version but by the way, your data would be really more easy to exploit, like don't have any `parent_id` to 0 if it's not a parent Id (NULL for example) I also do not understand why do you have different `subscription_name`. I think you should work more on change your input instead of find a complexe algorithm to parse them

```
function tree(array $elements) {
    $openList = [];
    $result = [];
    $id = 0;
    foreach ($elements as $key => $element) {
        if($key != 0) // I suppose the trial one is not used
        {
            if($element['parent_id'] == 0) // a root
            {
                $closeList = [];
                $openList[$element['id']] = $element['id'];
                $result[$id] = $element;
                unset($result[$id]['parent_id']);
                $result[$id]['children'] = [];
                $newOpenlist = [];
                while(count($openList) > 0)
                {
                    foreach ($elements as $key => $element) {
                        if($element['parent_id'] != 0 && in_array($element['parent_id'], $openList) && !in_array($element['parent_id'], $closeList))
                        {
                            $newOpenlist[$element['id']] = $element['id'];
                            $result[$id]['children'][] = $element;
                        }
                    }
                    foreach($openList as $item)
                    {
                        $closeList[] = $item;
                    }
                    $openList = $newOpenlist;
                    $newOpenlist = [];
                }
            }
            $id++;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Your answer is very near to my desired output.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I do not clearly understand the logic behind the `subscription_name`. Regarding the `childrens` below code might work.

```
<?php

$array = [
  [
 'id' => 1,
 'subscription_name' => 'Yearly',
 'parent_id' => 0
],
   [
 'id' => 22,
 'subscription_name' => 'Yearly new',
 'parent_id' => 1
],
   [
 'id' => 23,
 'subscription_name' => 'Yearly new offer',
 'parent_id' => 22
],
   [
 'id' => 24,
 'subscription_name' => 'Weekly',
 'parent_id' => 0
],
   [
 'id' => 25,
 'subscription_name' => 'Weekly new offer',
 'parent_id' => 24
],

    ];
function find_childrens_parent_not_zero($array) {  

foreach($array as $key => $value) {

 if($value['parent_id'] != 0) {
    if(!is_array($array[$key]['childrens'])) {
      $array[$key]['childrens'] = [];
    }

    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
      if($v['parent_id'] == $value['id']) {
        array_push($array[$key]['childrens'], array('id' => $v['id']));
        unset($array[$k]['parent_id']);       
      }
    }
 }

}

return $array;
}

function find_childrens_parent_zero($array) {  

  foreach($array as $key => $value) {

   if($value['parent_id'] == 0) {
      if(!is_array($array[$key]['childrens'])) {
        $array[$key]['childrens'] = [];
      }

      foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        if($v['parent_id'] == $value['id']) {
          array_push($array[$key]['childrens'], array('id' => $v['id']));
          unset($array[$k]['parent_id']);       
        }
      }
   }

  }

  return $array;
  }
function merge_children($array) {

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
      if($value['parent_id'] == 0) { 
        //pluck childrens of it's children
        foreach($value['childrens'] as $k => $v) {
          foreach($array as $ke => $val) {
            if($v['id'] == $val['id']) {              
              $array[$key]['childrens'] = array_merge($array[$key]['childrens'], $array[$ke]['childrens']);

            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return $array;
}
/**
 * Remove parent not zero elements
 */
function cleanup_array($array) {
  $result = [];
  foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(array_key_exists('parent_id', $value )) {
      unset($value['parent_id']); 
      array_push($result, $value);  

     }
    }
    return $result;
}
echo '<pre>';
$result_parent_not_zero = find_childrens_parent_not_zero($array);
$result_parent_zero     = find_childrens_parent_zero($result_parent_not_zero);
$result_merged_children = merge_children($result_parent_zero);
$result_cleaned_up      = cleanup_array($result_merged_children);
print_r($result_cleaned_up);
```

Will give you the result as

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [subscription_name] => Yearly
            [childrens] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 22
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 23
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24
            [subscription_name] => Weekly
            [childrens] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 25
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: long code but still more clear and accurate than mine

Comment: @Krishnads PC, The logic behind subscription name is when user update subscription name then a new entry is inserted and the parent id of the new row is the old updated id(unique id ).

Comment: @ShubhamAzad That is what is happening in DB? From this array what we need to do? It is always better to fetch it the way you wanted from the DB itself.

Comment: @Krishnads, I know the better way to fetch the output by the query, but I am not understanding how can I fetch this output by the query. Then I fetch all records and rearranging with PHP array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$load[0]['id'] = 0;
$load[0]['subscription_name'] = 'Trial';
$load[0]['parent_id'] = 0;

$load[1]['id'] = 1;
$load[1]['subscription_name'] = 'Yearly';
$load[1]['parent_id'] = 0;

$load[2]['id'] = 2;
$load[2]['subscription_name'] = 'Trial';
$load[2]['parent_id'] = 1;

$load[3]['id'] = 3;
$load[3]['subscription_name'] = 'Yearly';
$load[3]['parent_id'] = 1;

$load[4]['id'] = 4;
$load[4]['subscription_name'] = 'Trial';
$load[4]['parent_id'] = 2;

function tree($load){
    $output = [];
    foreach($load as $l){
        $temp = [];
        foreach($load as $ll){
            if($ll['parent_id']==$l['id']){
                if($l['id']==$ll['id'])
                continue;
                $temp[] = $ll; 
            }
        }
        $l['childrens'] = $temp;
        $output[] = $l;
    }
    return $output;    
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(tree($load));
```

Comment: I do not think this is the desired output